# Stored Procedure without a CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My problem is i want to know how to write an sql statement that will **increase all acounts with balances over $10,0000 by 6%, all other accounts receive 5% (without using a CASE statement)**
The table involve in the statement is account table with the following fields:
(account_number(PK), branch_name, balance).
Thanks in advance...

Comment: why can't you use a case statement, what is the restriction? can we use multiple statements?

Comment: Why can't you write two queries?

Comment: I guess `$10,0000` is a typo and you mean `$ 10 thousand`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, this version of ypercube's script has only 1 update, and should do the job:

```
UPDATE tableX
SET balance = balance * (1 + ((5.00 + convert(bit,floor(balance/10000))) / 100))
```

Note: I've used 5.00 to force the division into decimals, and not round off as an int. You could also do this by doing it properly and converting to a decimal.

Comment: +1 The lengths you have to go to because someone has forbidden you to use CASE

Comment: My guess would be that it might be a homework/interview question to test ingenuity?

Comment: As for using 5.00 to force the non-integer division, it is unnecessary, which you can easily see for yourself: `SELECT (5.00 + 8/5)` returns `6.00`, not `6.60`. The only thing that matters is the type of `balance`, and if it is not integer (which is most probably the case), you don't need to worry. (Or, rather, Alieu doesn't need to worry.)

Comment: @Andriy. The example `(5.00 + 8/5)` does indeed return `6.00`, however using `(5 + (5.00 + 3)/5)` does return `6.60` - this is much more like what actually happens here. You need it here as the balance is reduced to a bit, so the only `balance` that acts as a decimal in the sum is the first one, which doesn't cause the calculation to work (eg `select 1.5 + (5 + 8/5)`) gives `7.5`, not `8.1`

Comment: Re homework/interview question – I wonder if consulting the SO community can be considered ingenuity, among other things... :)

Comment: Re 5.00 – I see, I overlooked the other division, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why `CASE` cannot be used. Anyway:

```
UPDATE tableX
SET  balance = balance * (1 + 0.06)
WHERE balance > 10000 ;

UPDATE tableX
SET  balance = balance * (1 + 0.05)
WHERE balance <= 10000
  AND balance > 0 ;
```

You probably want to put this inside a transaction.

---

Without using `CASE` and with only one `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.balance = x.balance * (1 + y.raise/100)
FROM tableX AS x
  JOIN
    ( SELECT 0 AS low, 10000 AS high, 5.0 AS raise
    UNION
      SELECT 10000, 9999999999, 6.0 
    ) AS y
    ON  x.balance > y.low 
    AND x.balance <= y.high
```

---

And one more approach, just for fun:

```
UPDATE tableX AS x
SET balance = balance * 
  ( SELECT TOP 1
        change
    FROM 
      ( SELECT 0 AS low, 1.05 AS change
      UNION
        SELECT 10000,    1.06 
      ) AS y
    WHERE balance > low
    ORDER BY low DESC
  )
WHERE balance > 0
```

Comment: Couple of things, the divisions here are integer divisions so will round off. Also I think the values of `raise` in the second version may be the wrong way around.

Comment: @Jon and @t-klausen.dk: thnx for the corrections. He may also need rounding the results to 2 decimal places but that depends on the type of the `balance` field.

Answer (score 3):

or this query :)), but is more stpid than Jon's query.

```
update tableX a set ballance = 
                    (select  ballance*(1+6/100) as  ballance_new 
                    from tableX b
                    where ballance >=10000 and b.account_name = a.account_name 
                    union all
                    select ballance*(1+5/100) as  ballance_new c
                    from tableX
                    where ballance <10000 and c.account_name = a.account_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is room for 1 more simple solution. Here it is:

```
UPDATE @t
SET balance = (SELECT balance* 1.05 where balance <= 10000
         UNION SELECT balance* 1.06 where balance > 10000)
```

Revised @AndriyM's surgested to use UNION ALL instead of UNION for better performance

```
UPDATE @t
SET balance = (SELECT balance* 1.05 where balance <= 10000
     UNION ALL SELECT balance* 1.06 where balance > 10000)
```

Comment: +1 Seemed improbable at first until I saw what was going on. UNION ALL might do better, though.

Comment: @AndriyM As it retrieve exactly 0 and 1 row, I assume union all and union performs the same

Comment: Yes, but I thought UNION would still infer the unnecessary sorting. Would it not?

Comment: Actually I shouldn't have asked. The query plan shows there *is* difference